# SqlDataReader.GetValue(0) cannot get anything

Tags: vb.net, sqldatareader

I am writing some script to read the sql query result at Intouch environment, it's not exactly C# language but similar. I just want to get the "1" stored in my "SQLTest" variable (Define as a string data type).

[Here's the result of my sql query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GoPKX.png)

And here is my code:

```
Dim objDB As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection;
Dim objCmd As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand;
Dim objDR As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader;
Dim objTbl As System.Data.DataTable;
Dim sDBConnStr As String;
Dim sSQL As String;
Dim bOk As Boolean;
sDBConnStr = "Server=Desktop-3J641FK;Database=Runtime;Integrated Security=True;";
'' Connect and open the database
objDB = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(sDBConnStr);
objDB.Open();
sSQL = "SELECT sum (case when EventLogKey = '5' and DetectDateTime between '2022-07-21 11:00:20' and '2022-07-25 11:00:20' then 1 else 0 end) FROM [Runtime].[dbo].[EventHistory]";
'' Invoke the SQL command
objCmd = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(sSQL, objDB);
'' Retrieve the queried fields from the query into the reader
objDR = objCmd.ExecuteReader();

InTouch:SQLTesting = objDR.Read();

while objDR.Read() == true

InTouch:SQLTest = objDR.GetValue(0).ToString;

endwhile;


objDR.Close();
objDB.Dispose();
objCmd.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 1):

```cs
InTouch:SQLTesting = objDR.Read();

while objDR.Read() == true
```

You are calling `Read` twice, so what do you expect to happen?

- If there will be exactly one row, just call `Read`.
- If there will be zero or one row, call `Read` with an `if` statement.
- If there may be more than one row, call `Read` with a `while` loop.

Do one and only one of the above. If there might be more than one row and you want to do something different if there are no rows, use the `HasRows` property first, then use the `while` loop.

Having said all that, if there will only be one value in the result set then you should be calling `ExecuteScalar`, so the data reader is irrelevant:

```cs
InTouch:SQLTest = objCmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

Comment: Because I need to have a variable to save the result of objDR.Read() to trace the issue, because Intouch/Wonderware script don't have any script troubleshooting tools for me. Anyway thanks for your help, I have found the issue of my script - The data type of the sql query output is an int32 instead of a string.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `While` loop is unnecessary here as you `Read` the sqldata reader already before `While` and you are using `Sum` in your sql which will return one value always. Try this :

```
InTouch:SQLTesting = objDR.Read();

InTouch:SQLTest = objDR.GetValue(0).ToString;
```